# How to create a desktop shortcut based upon user Input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am creating setup for a Windows Forms Application using Visual Studio 2010. I know how to create shortcut on the desktop during the setup. My question is,
**How to add a checkbox during the setup asking the user "Do you want to create a shortcut on the desktop"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out, adding your own checkboxes can be a bit cumbersome, but here is an in-depth guide I stumbled upon:

[Create custom dialogs for use in your Visual Studio Setup projects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi)

The article explains it for the VS2010 using Visual Studio's own installer dialogs and would probably be the way to go.

For VS2003 there is a bit different guide, might be worth checking out:
[Conditional Install of Desktop and Quick Launch Shortcuts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11758/Conditional-Install-of-Desktop-and-Quick-Launch-Sh)

(possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472357/visual-studio-deployment-project-optional-desktop-shortcut))

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this in few days.